# how do I set up my gcc again

Tags: macos, bash, gcc

I've tried to set up CUDA and XCode on my mac to work together, but it failed.
During the process I went to `/usr/bin/` and type:

and typed `> sudo rm gcc`

then `> sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/gcc-4.2 gcc`

I think I screwed up something because now when I type in

```
> gcc
```

into the terminal, it says

```
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

how do I fix it and make the default gcc 4.2?

Comment: are you sure the link works? What does `which gcc-4.2` give you?

Comment: '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' is the result I get for that

Comment: so why are you linking to something in /opt/lobal/bin ?

Comment: b/c I'm stupid, just tried what you said, it worked
thank you, I love you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing

```
sudo ln -s $(which gcc-4.2) gcc
```

instead. This will find the version of `gcc-4.2` you've installed and link the default `gcc` to it.